# Sequelize – query overlapping dates with exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a an object with attributes like

```
from: '2021-04-24 16:00',
to: '2021-04-24 16:15',
```

I also want to make sure that there is no other object added to the database that overlaps with this date, unless it would have `to`, where `from` is set, or `from`, where the `to` is set.
Examples:

- `2021-04-24 15:45 - 16:00` – allowed
- `2021-04-24 15:46 - 16:01` – not allowed
- `2021-04-24 16:14 - 16:29` – not allowed
- `2021-04-24 16:15 - 16:30` – allowed

How can I query my database first to find whether an overlapping object exists, so I can prevent the creation?

I've tried with the `[Op.between]` operator, but it is inclusive so the 1st and 4th examples are also not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `[Op.and]`? Something like this:

```
[Op.and]: [{
    from: { [Op.lt]: "TO" },
}, {
    to: { [Op.gt]: "FROM" },
}],
```